# Generate time-series of any frequency in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I used to generate time-series in `R`using `xts` package as

```
library(xts)
seq <- timeBasedSeq('2015-06-01/2015-06-05 23')
z <- xts(1:length(seq),seq)
```

After a bit of tweaks, I find it easy to generate data at a default rate of 1 hour or 1 minute or 1 second. Reading the help page of `?timeBasedseq` does not clearly mention how to generate data at other frequncies. Say, I want to generate data at 10 minutes rate. Where Should I mention `M` (minutes) and 10 in the said command to generate 10 minutes data. Option `M` is mentioned in the help pages.

Comment: Why not just use `seq <- seq(as.POSIXct("2015-06-01"), as.POSIXct("2015-06-05"), by = "10 mins")`?

Comment: Yes, your approach serves the need definitely. But, I am little curious about `xts`. I read its vignette, but still, not find anything for variable frequency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. The "by" value is essentially hard-coded at 1 unit. It should be possible to patch the code so you can specify the "by" component as something like `"10M"` for 10-minutes, since `seq.POSIXct` would accept a `by = "10 mins"` value.

If you want, you can create an issue for this feature request and we can discuss details of what this patch should include.